# Ошибка при запуске бота 'This client already has an associated command tree'

Tags: python, discord.py

Пытаюсь освоить слэш-команды на discord.py. Прошерстила форумы, но решения своей проблемы не нашла. При запуске бота выдает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\vip_files\code\bot\testbot.py", line 9, in <module>
    tree = app_commands.CommandTree(bot)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\mimi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\tree.py", line 132, in __init__
    raise ClientException('This client already has an associated command tree.')
discord.errors.ClientException: This client already has an associated command tree.
PS D:\vip_files\code\bot>
```

Вот весь код:

```py
import discord
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands
 
TOKEN ='токен'

intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?', intents=intents)
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(bot)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
     await tree.sync(guild=discord.Object(id=id сервера))
     print('Im ready!')

# Клин
@tree.command(name = 'Клин', description = 'Очистка сообщений', guild=discord.Object(id=id сервера))
@commands.has_any_role(ids ролей)
async def клин(interaction: discord.Interaction, количество = 100):
    await interaction.channel.purge(limit = int(количество))
    await interaction.send('Готово!', ephemeral=True)

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Ошибка "discord.errors.ClientException: This client already has an associated command tree" возникает, когда вы пытаетесь создать новое дерево команд для клиента Discord, который уже имеет связанное дерево команд.

При использовании discord.app_commands.CommandTree вы должны вызывать метод sync() только один раз для каждого клиента. Вы пытаетесь вызвать sync() внутри функции on_ready(), которая может вызываться каждый раз при подключении бота к Discord.
---------------------
import discord
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands
 
TOKEN ='токен'

intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?', intents=intents)
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(bot)
tree.sync(guild=discord.Object(id=id_сервера))  # вынесли sync() за пределы on_ready()

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Im ready!')

# Клин
@tree.command(name='Клин', description='Очистка сообщений', guild=discord.Object(id=id_сервера))
@commands.has_any_role(ids_ролей)
async def клин(interaction: discord.Interaction, количество=100):
    await interaction.channel.purge(limit=int(количество))
    await interaction.send('Готово!', ephemeral=True)

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, нельзя использовать одновременно слеш-команды и команды без него. Либо то, либо то. Поэтому, напиши так:

```
import discord
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands
 
TOKEN ='токен'

intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
     await tree.sync(guild=discord.Object(id=id сервера))
     print('Im ready!')

# Клин
@tree.command(name = 'Клин', description = 'Очистка сообщений', guild=discord.Object(id=id сервера))
@commands.has_any_role(ids ролей)
async def клин(interaction: discord.Interaction, количество = 100):
    await interaction.channel.purge(limit = int(количество))
    await interaction.send('Готово!', ephemeral=True)

client.run(TOKEN)
```